# How to detect interactions with SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that keeps track of whether entities have interacted. So, for example, each row has a unique key, a date of interaction, an entity, and a group number. If two entities have been in the same group ever, they have interacted.

I have another table in which these entities are stored (with a unique identifier, a name, etc).

I need a query that tells me who hasn't interacted with whom, preferably in two columns, with the first being a single entity, and the second being a list of all of the entities it hasn't interacted with.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance - my SQL chops are quite rough!

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: The chances to get an answer are higher, if you post the structure of the tables (as `CREATE TABLE` statements), some sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements) and the desired result with that sample data (in a tabular format). Please also tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Definitely possible, and there are lots of existing answers for nearly this question. Give the tables as per @stickybit and you will get an answer.

Comment: Also, change the title. It's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two tables based on your requirement. This will work in sql server, not sure of your database.

The tables and the result of this data showing all interactions is here:

```
-- Entities
create table entity(e_id int, name varchar(20))
insert entity values (1,'tom'),(2,'dick'),(3,'harry')

-- Interactions
create table interaction(i_id int, e_id int, group_id int)
insert interaction values (1,1,1), (2,2,1)

-- Show all interaction
select distinct e1.name as n1, e2.name as n2
from interaction i
join interaction i2 on i2.group_id=i.group_id and i2.e_id!=i.e_id
join entity e1 on e1.e_id=i.e_id
join entity e2 on e2.e_id=i2.e_id
```

This gives you this:

```
n1      n2
dick    tom
tom     dick
```

Then to give you the result you are after, this query will do it:

```
-- Final select
; with nlist as (
    select e1.name as n1, e2.name as n2
    from entity e1
    join entity e2 on e2.e_id<>e1.e_id
    where not exists (
        select * from interaction i1
        join interaction i2 on i2.group_id=i1.group_id
        where i1.e_id=e1.e_id
        and i2.e_id=e2.e_id
    )
)
SELECT n1,  No_Interaction = STUFF(
        (
        SELECT ',' + n2 
        FROM nlist t1
        WHERE t1.n1 = t2.n1
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        )
        , 1, 1, '') 
from nlist t2
group by n1;
```

Result is:

```
n1      No_Interaction
dick    harry
harry   tom,dick
tom     harry
```